# How to scale an element to the maximum possible view area?

Tags: css

Presume you have a simple image website that's simply meant to display pictures as big as possible. Normally, that would be as simple as setting width and height to 100%, maintaining aspect ratio of course.

However, in my case, I got a (non-fixed) navbar at the top of the page. The simple solution is to simply reduce the maximum height, and while that works, it's kind of annoying once you scroll down.

How would I make it so that instead of setting a fixed height, the height is set dynamically by what **could be displayed at once**?

Here's what I mean:

[image: Schematic]

The gray rectangle is the navbar, the white square is the default element height, while the transparent square is the same element scaling up and eventually filling the entire screen while scrolling down and slowly making the navbar disappear.

Bonus points if this only works in one direction, so the image doesn't become smaller again once scrolling past it.

Comment: Can you post the html and css code? Hard to know without seeing what you did at DOM level.

Comment: Nothing yet, because I wouldn't even know where to start. I'm mostly trying to find out how one would do this in general because I swear I've seen this before somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are, as you understand, relative to the parent container. However, if you instead want to set width and/or height to the size of the **viewport** then please look into the CSS units `vh` and `vw` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know about those, but they only take the windows size into account, not the contents _inside_ the webpage. At least not as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a (video) demo of what you are trying to create?

Comment: I guess the image isn't clear enough? A video would be too difficult to make. I can try some more mockup images. Give me a while.